# Hide text in text box but not entire input box using query

Tags: jquery

Any way to hide the text in the text box of a html input field, but not hide the entire box? I am using http://opensource.teamdf.com/number/examples/demo-as-you-type.html   and when the document loads, the text appears as 0.00 and I only want it to be blank until the user starts typing. It work perfectly fine in the demo. Any suggestions? or an alternative to hide the text only not the entire input box  and `.val()`  does not work

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: $('selector').val(" "); .. Set value to empty in initial state

Comment: .val("") does not work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the text that is in a text box, `$('#foo').val('')` will set the value in the text box to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be sufficient if you just want to clear the textbox.

```
$( document ).ready(){
$('#ID_of_your_textbox').val('');
}
```

if you want to preserve value before clearing just push it in some variable.
**UPDATE** 
Okay after you updated the link i saw what is happening , it is not necessary for you to use that plugin here is the code that will do exact same. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wddeumre/)
Along with blur you can call the same function on focus lost key press to make it same as the plugin